# Получить тех.процесс и мощность процессора CPU

Tags: ос, cpu, fasm

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь найти способ идентификации **CPU**, и начал с инструкции **CPUID**. Но как оказалось она возвращает всё, кроме вольтажа, потребляемой мощности и тех.процесса ядра, по типу **45nm**, **14nm** и т.д. Кто-нибудь знает, где система хранит эту информацию и как её можно считать с прикладного уровня? Может есть какие-нибудь **Win32-API** или в **реестре**. Спасибо.

Comment: Думаю, что тех процесс просто по имени процессора из таблички берется

Comment: @KoVadim по сути я тоже это подозревал. Видимо из баз берутся так-же кодовое имя ядра (по Model/Steping), тип сокета и мощность. А вот текущее напряжение я нашёл в таблице SMBios, используя программу RW. Программно считать её можно через `GetSystemFirmwareTable()`

Comment: Вольтаж, в теории, можно получить из данных WMI, но, по опыту, сильно зависит от платформы и ещё чего-то